# nimble : Warning: Using project local deps mode or how to switch deps mode for nimble

Tags: nim-lang, nimble-nim

Happy new year, everyone ! :)

I tried to run `nimble list -i` command, but mistyped with `nimble list -l` and now when I run this `nimble list -i` command again to get all installed packages ...
 I get:

> Warning: Using project local deps mode

... and without list of installed packages. 
 I get the list of installed packages only when I change directory from C: to D:

Is it normal behavior ? Or do I have to be in the same directory as my Nim project folders to do this ? 
 Or did I break something with `nimble list -l` command ?

**Update** : I tried to run `nimble list -l` command on D: directory too, and now `nimble list -i` shows me same

> Warning: Using project local deps mode

So, now my question is how to get rid of this *deps mode* for nimble ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how to fix this just by deleting `nimbledeps` directory from directory where I runned this command.

Sorry for stupid questions and stupid fixes. :D